# How-to generate a set of random points in a dynamic region

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction

**Description**

It probably has a simple fix but I can't seem to find a way.

I am looking to generate a set of random points within a dynamic region. Each time a new type of region is selected, the random points must be generated accordingly to fit within region boundaries. Please see an example below.

**Example:**

**Code**

```
 DynamicModule[
 {
  shape = {},
  targets
  },
 Panel @ Column @ {
    Item[RadioButtonBar[Dynamic @ shape, {Disk[] -> "Disk", Rectangle[] -> "Rectangle"}], Alignment -> Center],

    Dynamic[targets = If[Length @ shape != 0, RandomPoint[shape, 10]]];

    Dynamic @ Graphics[{
       {FaceForm @ White, EdgeForm @ Black, shape},
       Point @ # & /@ targets
       }]
    }
 ]
```

**Output**

[image: Error Message]

**Error**

> targets$$ is not a Graphics primitive or directive

However if in the following line of code (see below) `;` is replaced with `,`, the code works but it also displays all the `{x,y}` coordinate pairs. I would like to avoid that.

**Code**

```
Dynamic[targets = If[Length @ shape != 0, RandomPoint[shape, 10]]];
```

**Output**

[image: working example]

I am after similar output as above but without displaying `{x,y}` coordinates.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would suggest using the second argument of `Dynamic`:

```
DynamicModule[{shape = Disk[], targets = RandomPoint[Disk[], 10]},
 Panel@Column@{
    Item[
     RadioButtonBar[Dynamic[
       shape,
       (targets = RandomPoint[#, 10]; shape = #) &
       ], {Disk[] -> "Disk", Rectangle[] -> "Rectangle"}],
     Alignment -> Center
     ],
    Dynamic@Graphics[{
       {FaceForm@White, EdgeForm@Black, shape},
       Point@# & /@ targets
       }]
    }]
```

[image]

The second argument is used to tell `Dynamic` what to do when the selection in the button bar is changed. By default `Dynamic` just updates its first argument to the corresponding value, but you can also tell it to "first update `targets` and then update `shape`".

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful, I knew there was an easy work around this issue. I will accept the answer later in the day (travelling)